# Initializing strings in C in Visual Studio

Tags: c, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I try to learn the XOR algorithm using C. I have found a great example on [KyleBank's GitHub](https://github.com/KyleBanks/XOREncryption/blob/master/C/main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {
    char key[] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Can be any chars, and any size array

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key)/sizeof(char))];
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char baseStr[] = "kylewbanks.com";

    char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(baseStr, encrypted);
    printf("Encrypted:%s\n", encrypted);

    char decrypted[strlen(baseStr)];
    encryptDecrypt(encrypted, decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted:%s\n", decrypted);
}
```

The above works well under Linux and gcc.
However, it does not compile in Visual Studio under Windows.

[image]

I am using build tools included in Visual Studio 2017.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `char encrypted[strlen(baseStr)];` is one too small. Even for "Linux and gcc"

Comment: Perhaps _Visual Studio 2017_, even when code compiled in C does not support VLAs.  With C11, VLA support is optional.  With C99, when it was introduced, VLA is required.

Comment: This isn't C++, it's C, which has VLAs, but Microsoft is notorious for being many years behind the standard. There might be a flag you have to set somewhere to tell the compiler to use C99, or it might just not support it. I you want to program in C, use a real compiler like GCC.

Comment: In fact, I'm inclined to suspect that Microsoft was influential in the committee's decision to take the compatibility-breaking step of making VLA support optional in C2011.  MS has always been more fond of \*ahem\* *persuading* people to adopt MS convention and practice than of complying or supporting with 3rd-party standards.

Comment: No, Microsoft doesn't support VLAs in MSVC and never will.

Comment: Note that the _output_ window in Visual Studio provides a plain text representation of the compiler output that you can copy & paste rather posting a _picture_ of text.

Comment: It would be fairly trivial to slightly refactor this code to work with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @JohnBollinger not as much as you'd think, the bigger issue was that VLAs caused more problems for the C compiler than they were worth. The feature had a lot of limitations that weren't worth the time to try and fix when actually implemented. For example most C programs have much smaller stack sizes than C++ etc. So a VLA could easily cause a Seg Fault/Stack Overflow by just being too large.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : I doubt that Microsoft had any interest whatsoever; they declare support only for ISO C90/ANSI C89 in their C compiler.  They made C++ the preferred language for Windows development many years ago, and essentially froze their C compiler - it supports only the C99 or later features that are also valid C++.  When C++ was still largely a superset of C that made a lot of sense.  Besides VLAs are just a really bad idea and a recipe for unsafe stack-blowing code.  Moreover in this specific example entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Note that `strlen()` has to iterate the string to find the end, then you iterate the string to perform the en/decrypt.  It would be far more efficient to have the iteration simply terminate when the end of the input (nut terminator) is encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's compiler does not support C99 VLAs (see the note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).  Array sizes must be a constant expression.  The code is also broken because it fails accommodate and place a nul terminator in the output.

In this case, `decrypted` and `encrypted` might be declared thus:

```
char encrypted[sizeof(baseStr)] ;
...
char decrypted[sizeof(baseStr)] ;
```

And `encryptDecrypt()` modified thus:

```
void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) {

...

    output[i] = 0 ;
}
```

Finally the signed mismatch warning may be cleaned up by declaring `i` as type `size_t`.

On Windows of course you could always use MinGW/GCC if you want more modern C support. Or you could use C++ and `std::string` or `std::vector` containers if you want to stick with Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: I am not invalidating your answer. I just mentioned `malloc`, I don't think it needs a separate answer.

Comment: Fine, I deleted my comment from your answer and added comment to the question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Appreciated, but consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment - specifically _"Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [...]Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);"_. - It really deserves an answer.  Comments are not indexed for search, so are of less value to the community, and SO is not a discussion forum.  As a generic solution to avoiding the need for VLAs yours is useful - even if not necessary in this very narrow example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation. Requires `#include <stdlib.h>`

```
char baseStr[] = "123";
char *encrypted = malloc(strlen(baseStr) + 1);
...
free(encrypted);
```

As mentioned before, you have to add 1 for the null-terminated character at the end.

The `char*` pointer is one piece of information, it shows where the string begins. But where does it end? `strlen` and other C functions have no idea where the string ends, so they go through all the characters until a `'\0'` character is encountered.

For efficiency, take `strlen(input)` out of the loop and calculate it only once:

```
void encryptDecrypt(char *input, char *output) 
{
    char key[] = { 'K', 'C', 'Q' };
    int keysize = sizeof(key);
    size_t i;
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        output[i] = input[i] ^ key[i % keysize];
    output[len] = 0; //will be same as output[i] = 0; 
}
```

The function `int main` should return zero. Note that this method cannot be described as "encryption" by modern standards. You can call it "obfuscation".